# Typescript generic "cast" function

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function that allows me to cast all object properties (I only have plain objects) to specific type. For the time being I only want to cast to primitives `boolean`, `string` and `number`. Something along these lines:

```
function castMembers<TObject extends object, TValue extends boolean | string | number>(instance: TObject, type: TValue): Record<keyof TObject, TValue> {
    Object.keys(instance).reduce((result, k) => {
        // ERROR
        result[k] = new type(instance[k]).valueOf();
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

In the future I may extend my casting to some whatever type as long as it satisfies my interface definition which would define that it must include `valueOf` function. So...

I'm well aware that I can't really instantiate new objects based on generic types, as they're only for compile time. That's why I added the second parameter so I can provide constructor function that should be used for casting. But Im getting an error, or I invalidly wrote my `TValue` generic param or the type of my second parameter.

**How to write such a function?**

## Edit

I've tried introducing a constructor interface, which gets me very close but I still get an error:

```
interface IConstructor<TValue> {
    new(value?: any): TValue;
}

function castMembers<TObject extends object, TValue extends number | string | boolean>(instance: TObject, toType: IConstructor<TValue>): Record<keyof TObject, TValue> | never {
    return (Object.keys(instance) as (keyof TObject)[]).reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = new toType(instance[key]).valueOf() as TValue;
        return result;
    }, {} as Record<keyof TObject, TValue>);
}
```

[Here's some code to play with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IConstructor%3CTValue%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(value%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20TValue%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20cast%3CTObject%20extends%20object%2C%20TValue%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%20%7C%20boolean%3E(instance%3A%20TObject%2C%20toType%3A%20IConstructor%3CTValue%3E)%3A%20Record%3Ckeyof%20TObject%2C%20TValue%3E%20%7C%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(Object.keys(instance)%20as%20(keyof%20TObject)%5B%5D).reduce((result%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20new%20toType(instance%5Bkey%5D).valueOf()%20as%20TValue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%20as%20Record%3Ckeyof%20TObject%2C%20TValue%3E)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Acast(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20123%0D%0A%7D%2C%20Boolean)%3B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've solved it myself while playing around to make it work. And I finally did it.
**This is the code.**

```
interface IPrimitiveLike<T> {
    valueOf(): T;
}

interface IConstructor<T> {
    readonly prototype: IPrimitiveLike<T>;
    new(value?: any): IPrimitiveLike<T>;
}

export default function castMembers<TObject extends object, TValue extends IPrimitiveLike<unknown>>(instance: TObject, toType: IConstructor<TValue>): Record<keyof TObject, TValue> | never {
    return (Object.keys(instance) as (keyof TObject)[]).reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = new toType(instance[key]).valueOf() as TValue;
        return result;
    }, {} as Record<keyof TObject, TValue>);
}
```

This code will correctly do:

```
let obj = {
    text: 'test',
    value: 123,
    negative: 0,
    bool: true
};
castMembers(obj, Boolean); // { text: true, value: true, negative: false, bool: true }
castMembers(obj, String); // { text: 'test', value: '123', negative: '0', bool: 'true' }
castMembers(obj, Custom); // also works if your custom class defines a valueOf() function
```

The only thing I'm not completely sure about is the use of `unknown` type. It can of course be replaced by `any`, but ideally it should be the primitive type related to the `valueOf` return type.

Comment: @H.B. Don't worry. I just need to wait another day to do so.